# Merge 2 objects and remove duplicates

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to merge 2 JSON URL and remove duplicates. Each JSON URL has the same object data(department) but inside that data it has another object name job and that will be my basis to merge the job object into department. I already retrieve using `getJSON` function and merge them but how can I remove the duplicate based on the inner Object data(job)?

I'm using [greenhouse](https://developers.greenhouse.io/harvest.html) API to get the Jobs

Code:

```
var getJSON = function (url, callback) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.responseType = "json";
xhr.onload = function () {
  var status = xhr.status;
  if (status === 200) {
    callback(null, xhr.response);
  } else {
    callback(status, xhr.response);
  }
};
xhr.send();
};

var mergeJobBoard = [];
getJSON(
  "https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/frequenceinc/departments/",
  function (error, data) {
    data.departments.forEach((department) => {
      mergeJobBoard.push(department);
    });
  }
);
getJSON(
  "https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/frequence/departments/",
  function (error, data) {
    data.departments.forEach((department) => {
      mergeJobBoard.push(department);
    });
    mergeJobBoard.forEach((department) => {
      if (department.jobs.length > 0) {
        console.log(department);
      }
    });
  }
);
```

Also sharing my sample results in github - https://github.com/pjv17/greenhouse-api-to-webflow

Comment: do you use lodash or something like that?

Comment: @cmgchess I don't use any library but I would love to check with that.

Comment: lodash has a merge or using pure js https://github.com/30-seconds/30-seconds-of-code/blob/master/snippets/merge.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) to download each object then using lodash [`merge`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge) to merge the results.

The lodash merge function does a very good job of merge objects, with well-tested code.

Once we download each object, we merge and display the result.

You can merge any number of objects with this code, simply add the url for each additional item.

To eliminate duplicate jobs, I'd suggest gathering the jobs into a `jobs` array, then using the [`_.uniq`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniq) function to eliminate duplicates.

```js
function downloadObject(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
}

async function combineObjects(urls) {
  const objectsToMerge = [];
  for(let url of urls) {
    console.log(`Downloading data from ${url}...`);
    const obj = await downloadObject(url);
    objectsToMerge.push(obj);
  }
  return  _.merge(...objectsToMerge);
}

async function testCombine() {
  const objectUrls = [
    'https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/frequenceinc/departments/',
    'https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/frequence/departments/'
  ]
  const result = await combineObjects(objectUrls);
  const jobs = result.departments.flatMap(entry => entry.jobs);
  console.log('Job count:', jobs.length);
  console.log('Job ids:', jobs.map(job => job.id).sort((a,b) => a-b));
  const uniqueJobs = _.uniq(jobs);
  console.log('Unique job count:', jobs.length);
  console.log('Unique job ids:', uniqueJobs.map(job => job.id).sort((a,b) => a-b));
}


testCombine();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I think this is a better approach but needs some minor fixes on merging because it removes the first job in 0 index of the first url.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your inputs guys! I have successfully setup it using pure Javascript using `filter` and `concat`. Here is my sample code below.

```
let mergeJobBoard = [];
getJSON(
  "https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/frequenceinc/departments/",
  function (error, data) {
    data.departments.forEach((department) => {
      mergeJobBoard.push(department);
    });
  }
);
getJSON(
  "https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/frequence/departments/",
  function (error, data) {
    data.departments.forEach((department) => {
      mergeJobBoard.push(department);
    });

    var output = [];
    mergeJobBoard.forEach((department) => {
      if (department.jobs.length > 0) {
        var existing = output.filter(function (v, i) {
          return v.id == department.id;
        });
        if (existing.length) {
          var existingIndex = output.indexOf(existing[0]);
          output[existingIndex].jobs = output[existingIndex].jobs.concat(
            department.jobs
          );
        } else {
          if (typeof department.jobs == "string")
            department.jobs = [department.jobs];
            output.push(department);
        }
      }
    });
    
    console.log(output);

    output.forEach((department) => {
        //additional codes
    });

  }
);
```